# Use the generic of a const as an interface

Tags: typescript

I'm using react-intl and they have a TypeScript definition for a FormattedNumber component:

```js
export declare const FormattedNumber: React.FC<UnifiedNumberFormatOptions & CustomFormatConfig & {
    value: number;
}>;
```

I'm using this in my React component that takes a prop `usdProps` allows you to override the props of a FormattedNumber component:

```js
<FormattedNumber
  value={numAmount}
  style="currency"
  currency={unit}
  minimumFractionDigits={2}
  maximumFractionDigits={2}
  {...usdProps}
/>
```

How can I set the props of my component to be generic of FormattedNumber without copying that exact generic?

Right now I can do this:

```js
interface Props {
  usdProps?: UnifiedNumberFormatOptions &
    CustomFormatConfig & {
    value: number;
  };
}
```

But I'd prefer it to be directly coupled to FormattedNumbers (fake example):

```js
interface Props {
  usdProps?: genericsOf FormattedNumbers;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the type `React.FC<T>` depends [structurally](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing) on its generic type parameter `T` (i.e., it actually uses `T` as opposed to [ignoring it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-doesnt-type-inference-work-on-this-interface-interface-foot--)), then you should be able to use [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types) to extract `T` from `React.FC<T>`, like this:

```
interface Props {
    usdProps?: typeof FormattedNumber extends React.FC<infer T> ? T : never
}
```

You can verify that this type is the same as your manual version.

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFA0wCeYWcAqgHbAHBYAmAcgFcQAIyxQAYtBDIYAeTAxgEdugC8cAN5xB7AhABccGFEEsAvgG44AehtwA7gAtZWAG7j6TFgGFBqGBIpKBkYHxVuAHM4DW1cAlwjEzM4K1t7Z1c3AC86LAAPSFg4XixcABtkSjhcFQC4YNCYPiFRcSNsPBgAOgkfAB4OLh4BYTFJaVkFJTq4ADI4PwCgybCI4GiFzRo4Xbg3ZHKzI3Yx8UsacwA+C5pgdmaoAjwWAAViMHRtvZ1UXneIJ8APxJbwQAgNVbNUZtKBwArNdi8dCdfC9Ab3AjiOAAFSucCBuLgJ3cnnMNBsSHKEAgAGt0JEabwDDQABRgD7iRgASjgAM+3X8-w+qBBcFZQ24LTOExCU0UylU80W-kCIEasnCeg2yu+ewORywJxlF3MvIAPjokVhuOw+HAaAh7EA)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the answer and the links!

Answer (score 0):

You want to extract the props of a component to use it in your own component. But there is no way to do that.

Since the props where declared using the generic type `<UnifiedNumberFormatOptions & CustomFormatConfig & { value: number; }>` if you want to use it you need to declare it the same way.

What you can do to achieve the same result is declare it as a type:

```
type FormattedNumberProps = UnifiedNumberFormatOptions & CustomFormatConfig & { value: number; };
```

and use it on your interface:

```
interface Props {
  usdProps?: FormattedNumberProps;
}
```